# git folder under version control but deleted from working copy

Tags: git

I am going to be creating an installer/upgrade script for my program. When deployed it would be dangerous to leave the install directory accessible and will be deleted from my working copy.

What is the best way to manage this in git? Is it ok just to delete the install directory? I just don't want it to get recreated if something changes in the install folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe to delete the folder, unless you are going to be doing something like

```
git reset --hard
```

or

```
git checkout -- Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hook to run

```
git rm -r <path to install folder>
```

This will remove it from the filesystem and the index; however, it might cause a merge conflict the next time you push with modifications to the install folder.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file ".git/info/exclude" and define all files inside install folder (install/*) as ignored files.